# Create key to group xml nodes with xslt language?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```
 <root xmlns="">
<General>
  <Data>
    <Number>123456</Number>
    <Date>2018-10-22</Data>
    <LineRefer>0001</LineRefer>
    <LineRefer>0002</LineRefer>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <Number>789456</Number>
    <Date>2018-10-22</Data>
    <LineRefer>0003</LineRefer>
    <LineRefer>0004</LineRefer>
  </Data>
</General>
<Services>
  <Details>
    <LineNumber>0001</LineNumber>
    <Description>test description</Description>
  </Details>
  <Details>
    <LineNumber>0002</LineNumber>
    <Description>test description</Description>
  </Details>
  <Details>
    <LineNumber>0003</LineNumber>
    <Description>test description</Description>
  </Details>
  <Details>
    <LineNumber>0004</LineNumber>
    <Description>test description</Description>
  </Details>
 </root>
```

I wish I could group to get this result

**number 123456**
0001 test description
0002 test description
**number 789456**
0003 test description
0004 test description

This is my xsl for xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
       <head>
    <title>HTML Document Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <xsl:for-each select="root" >
        <xsl:for-each select="Services/Details" >
          <ul>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="LineNumber" /> | <xsl:value-of   select="Description" /> </li>
        </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result

0001 test description
0002 test description
0003 test description
0004 test description

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far ? Check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also your XML seems incorrect (typo maybe ?) `</Data>` instead of `</Date>` and no `</Services>`

Comment: From what I see, the data is already grouped. All you need to do is fetch the descriptions from the corresponding lines. For this, it is best to use a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key).

Comment: @micheal.hor257k : I can see a list of services but I can not insert the line of Data . How can I use the key ?

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you mean by that. Post your current XSLT, so we can help you fix it. -- And try to spell my name correctly, so that I get notified.

Comment: It sounds like you are selecting the `Services/Details` elements, and then trying to get the associated `Data` element. If so, you should reverse the logic. Start off by getting the `Data` elements, and for each `Data` element, use the key to get the services.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : sorry for my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making things more difficult for yourself by trying to select the `Services/Details` first, as you would have to worry about grouping. However, the data is already "grouped" in your `General/Data` elements, so instead start off by selecting these.

To get the details of the relevant `Services/Details` first define a key....

```
<xsl:key name="services" match="Services/Details" use="LineNumber" />
```

Then, when positioned on a `Data` elements, you can get all relevant details like so...

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('services', LineRefer)">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:key name="services" match="Services/Details" use="LineNumber" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>HTML Document Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="page">
        <xsl:for-each select="General/Data" >
          <h1><xsl:value-of select="Number" /></h1>
          <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('services', LineRefer)">
               <li><xsl:value-of select="LineNumber" /> | <xsl:value-of   select="Description" /> </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRw for this in action.

Do note, your XML shows `xmlns=""` on the `root` element. If, in your actual XML, this `xmlns` is not empty, then this means your XML elements are all in a default namespace, and the above XSLT won't work.

If this is the case, you should change the XSLT to account for the namespace. There are many examples of how to handle the default namespace in XSLT 1.0 here on StackOverflow, but as I am feeling Christmassy, have a look at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRw/1 for an example.